# Should I delete the string members of a C++ class?

Tags: c++, string

If I have the following declaration:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class DEMData
{
private:
    int bitFldPos;
    int bytFldPos;
    std::string byteOrder;
    std::string desS;
    std::string engUnit;
    std::string oTag;
    std::string valType;
    int idx;
public:
    DEMData();
    DEMData(const DEMData &d);
    void SetIndex(int idx);
    int GetIndex() const;
    void SetValType(const char* valType);
    const char* GetValType() const;
    void SetOTag(const char* oTag);
    const char* GetOTag() const;
    void SetEngUnit(const char* engUnit);
    const char* GetEngUnit() const;
    void SetDesS(const char* desS);
    const char* GetDesS() const;
    void SetByteOrder(const char* byteOrder);
    const char* GetByteOrder() const;
    void SetBytFldPos(int bytFldPos);
    int GetBytFldPos() const;
    void SetBitFldPos(int bitFldPos);
    int GetBitFldPos() const;
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, DEMData d);
    bool operator==(const DEMData &d) const;
    ~DEMData();
};
```

what code should be in the destructor?  Should I "delete" the `std::string` fields?

Comment: A comment on style: Instead of returning `const char*` from functions, I'd prefer to return `const std::string&`. This is possible when the string returned is a member of the object. And similarly for input, I'd prefer `const std::string&`

Comment: Did you even bother to try this before you posted the question?  You couldn't delete those strings, even if you wanted to.

Comment: Sometimes you can see people calling `clear()` on standard containers before they go out of scope ("deleting" in this sense). That won't be necessary either.

Comment: Because all your members manage their resources themselves, you don't need a copy-constructor, assignment operator (which you're missing; very bad to overload the copy-constructor but not the assignment operator!), or a destructor. The *point* of RAII is you don't need to manage resources, they manage themselves.

Comment: @Amit:  One issue with returning `const std::string&` is that the value must exist after the function exits.  This *may* require a `static` instance in the method.  Another issue is that other parts of the OP's code may use `char *` rather than `std::string`.  And finally, `char *` can be constants in Read Only Memory, while `std::string` must be created during run-time.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your destructor only has to destroy the members for which you allocate resources. so no, you don't "delete" strings.

You *delete* pointers you allocate with *new*

Your destructor doesn't have to be more than

```
~DEMData()
{
}
```

Comment: in fact you can leave that destructor out. the compiler will make it for you

Comment: And the compiler will generate that for you if you don't supply it.

Answer (score 7):

No, the std::string members are allocated automatically on the stack or heap for you and are cleaned up automatically.  You do not have to do anything special in your destructor to handle the strings.

Comment: On the stack? Only if the `DEMData` instance is on the stack.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you can't say if the std::string object itself is on the stack or the heap since you don't know how DEMData is being constructed.  The contained string will be on the heap unless the implementation of std::string uses the std::string object itself to store the string for short strings.

Answer (score 6):

No, you should not delete the `std::string` objects. they will be automatically freed up when their destructor's gets called.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a destructor (nor a copy constructor, nor an overloaded assignment operator). That's the whole point of using a class like string that does things for you, rather than going with C-style strings and manual memory management.

The compiler produces all the afore-mentioned for you and by default the destructor just invokes the destructors of all members (this happens implicitly even after a user-defined destructor completes). String's destructor takes over from there.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer as it answers the "thing" that bothered the OP:
> by default the destructor just invokes the destructors of all members (this happens implicitly even after a user-defined destructor completes).